# How to debug SignalR messages in Blazor Server

Tags: blazor, microsoft-edge, chromium, blazor-server-side, web-developer-toolbar

is there a better way to debug communication between Blazor Server and the browser than the binary messages in Chromium developer tools:

[image]

Comment: messages sent to server and from server

Comment: Can this [document](https://medium.com/@dwivedi.gourav/asp-net-core-signalr-signalr-debugging-tool-a82dc5230035) help you?